# Computer Guesses Your Number

Tags: c++

I need to make a "Guessing game" but I'm stuck because I'm not sure if this is the right way to make it, since it's so hard to actually find the number I'm thinking of when playing the game.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int guess;
int n=500;
cout<<"Think of a number from 1 to 1000."<<endl;
cout<<"The number is : 1. 500"<<endl;
cout<<"2. Bigger than 500"<<endl;
cout<<"3. Smaller than 500"<<endl;
cin>>guess;

while(n<=2000)
{
    if(guess==1)
    {
        cout<<"The computer has guessed the number!";
        break;
    }
    else if(guess==2)
    {
        n+=n/2;
        cout<<"The number is :\n1."<<n<<endl;
        cout<<"2. Bigger than "<<n<<endl;
        cout<<"3. Smaller than "<<n<<endl;
        cin>>guess;
    }
    else if(guess==3)
    {
        n-=n/2;
        cout<<"The number is :\n1."<<n<<endl;
        cout<<"2. Bigger than "<<n<<endl;
        cout<<"3. Smaller than "<<n<<endl;
        cin>>guess;
    }
  }
}
```

I can't seem to find a better way to make the game. The number always goes over `1000` so I had to set the `while` to under `2000` for it to work.

It would be good if I could set the `n+=n/2` formula so that it splits the last number that was the `n` variable. For example : `500+(500/2)`, then `750+(250/2)`, then `875+(125/2)` (not sure how it would continue when the `125` will get split into `62.5`) or the same with the `n-=n/2`.

Comment: if the number is known to be over 500, you never want to select a 500 or less ever again. Store a min and a max and keep picking numbers between the min and max, moving the min or max when the user provides new information.

Comment: @edlars47. Read this example: [guessing game](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/115091/) for inspiration

Comment: This isn't a C++ problem, it's a logic problem. I recommend pen, paper and patience!

Comment: Look up "binary search". You're on the right track but your implementation is flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int guess;
    int min = 0, current = 500, max = 1000;
    cout << "Think of a number from 1 to 1000." << endl;
    cout << "The number is : 1. 500" << endl;
    cout << "2. Bigger than 500" << endl;
    cout << "3. Smaller than 500" << endl;
    cin >> guess;
    while (current <= 2000)
    {
        if (guess == 1)
        {
            cout << "The computer has guessed the number!";
            break;
        }
        else if (guess == 2)
        {
            min = current;
            current = (min + max) / 2;

            cout << "The number is :\n." << current << endl;
            cout << "2. Bigger than " << current << endl;
            cout << "3. Smaller than " << current << endl;
            cin >> guess;
        }
        else if (guess == 3)
        {
            max = current;
            current = (min + max) / 2;
            cout << "The number is :\n." << current << endl;
            cout << "2. Bigger than " << current << endl;
            cout << "3. Smaller than " << current << endl;
            cin >> guess;
        }
    }
}
```

This should work. the `min` and `max` effectively restrict the domain after each guessing.

Comment: also, int variable doesn't have decimals. it will round if an odd number is divided by 2.

Comment: `while (current <= 2000)` is useless as an exit condition.

Comment: yep, forgot to delete that